# String of bytes to byte array

Tags: java, string, arrays

I am reading an array of bytes from a page as a String. Example: `"80 75 7 8 0 0"`.
I would like to convert this String into a byte array in Java. Can anyone help me/tell me what method I can possibly use?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the separator? Space?

Comment: Why are you reading the array of bytes as a `String` in the first place?

Comment: Split the string  by spaces and cast every string to byte

Comment: @nitegazer2003 read the question better

Comment: Yes, the separator is space. I will try as BackSlash said. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
String[] bytesString = originalString.split(" ");
byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesString.length];
for(int i = 0 ; i < bytes.length ; ++i) {
    bytes[i] = Byte.parseByte(bytesString[i]);
}
```